# Trying to add timestamp to image but keep getting error unknown image property "%[exif:DateTimeOriginal]"

Tags: bash, imagemagick, image-processing

I want to put timestamps on all images in a directory based on the date created/modified.

I've seen a bunch of methods like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/649033/ubuntu-add-timestamp-to-image) and [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1235238), but they all use the code `%[exif:DateTimeOriginal]` which results in an error for me.

I can use the following code

```
convert input.png -annotate +100+100  "Hello" output.png
```

But I want to use this instead

```
convert input.png -annotate +100+100  %[exif:DateTimeOriginal] output.png
```

But it results in this error:

```
convert.im6: unknown image property "%[exif:DateTimeOriginal]" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3245.
```

Does anyone know a fix or can anyone suggest an alternative?

Comment: Add version of ImageMagick to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that the EXIF tag `DateTimeOriginal` is not present in your image file, meaning that you can't use it to annotate the image.

Comment: I thought that might be true, but I tried a ton of different images and I thought at least one would have it. Is there an alternative to DateTimeOriginal I could use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still out there, but perhaps for other users this might help.   Sometimes you can use the "file" command to see the metadata of your file.   In mine, I could use the "timedate" tag